# When to use IQueryable as Return type in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, breeze

If defined return type as `IQueryable` then my ajax call fail some time.

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Banner> GetBannerForExcel()
    {
        return this._banneruow.Repository.GetAll();
    }
```

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error and unable to debug also;

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{4acaf0ef-4230-404d-ae26-304916e1c044} Line Number 1, Column 1:

So when I use return type `List<Banner>` it works perfect without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller returns OData format, the response body from your action that returns IQueryable will contain more information such as next page of data, odata metadata. IQueryable supports further filtering, paging, but it doesn't support random access via indexer. List supports random access via indexer and doesn't support further filtering. In your case if you need only data on the client side then return List or IEnumerable.

IQueryable is better choice for data-tier (server side), because it defer execution.

I also would recommend you to trace what you are getting back from a server when you use IQueryable and List using browser dev tools, or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

You can find more information here:

[IQueryable, IEnumerable or List](http://forums.asp.net/t/1286667.aspx?IQueryable%20T%20IEnumerable%20T%20or%20List%20T%20)

[Implement Efficient Data Paging](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/implement-efficient-data-paging)

[To return IQueryable or not return IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718624/to-return-iqueryablet-or-not-return-iqueryablet)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time with us. Yes I am using OData format. I want to filter record by ID Basis after i click on filter shows fail error code 500. I unable to error track it.

Comment: After long effort found issue i haven't set copy local true for Microsoft.Data.OData.dll so it showing error on live application.